# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Incorrect response id: (request id: 1)'

Tags: php, json-rpc, limesurvey

I am using limesurvay **github.com/trougakoss/LimeSurvey** with **github.com/weberhofer/jsonrpcphp** and code for testing is

```
require_once 'C:/wamp/www/limesurvey/jsonrpcphp/src/org/jsonrpcphp/jsonRPCClient.php';
define( 'LS_BASEURL', 'http://10.10.10.29:823/limesurvey/index.php?r=admin/remotecontrol');  // adjust this one to your actual LimeSurvey URL
define( 'LS_USER', 'admin' );
define( 'LS_PASSWORD', 'admin' );

// the survey to process
$survey_id=989315;

// instanciate a new client
$myJSONRPCClient = new \org\jsonrpcphp\JsonRPCClient( LS_BASEURL);

//echo $myJSONRPCClient->getinfo();
// receive session key
$sessionKey= $myJSONRPCClient->get_session_key( LS_USER, LS_PASSWORD );

// receive all ids and info of groups belonging to a given survey
$groups = $myJSONRPCClient->list_groups( $sessionKey, $survey_id );
print_r($groups, null );

// release the session key
$myJSONRPCClient->release_session_key( $sessionKey );
```

and geting these errors: output result

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Incorrect response id: (request id: 1)' in C:\wamp\www\limesurvey\jsonrpcphp\src\org\jsonrpcphp\JsonRPCClient.php on line 185

( ! ) Exception: Incorrect response id: (request id: 1) in C:\wamp\www\limesurvey\jsonrpcphp\src\org\jsonrpcphp\JsonRPCClient.php on line 185

Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function                                            Location
1   1.0022  252616  {main}( )                                           ..\test.php:0
2   1.0032  295944  org\jsonrpcphp\JsonRPCClient->get_session_key( )    ..\test.php:25
3   1.0032  296360  org\jsonrpcphp\JsonRPCClient->__call( )             ..\test.php:25
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when I forgot to enable JSON-RPC in Global Settings. Are you sure you enabled it? Just a thought.

"Go to Global settings, choose the tab 'Services' and select one of the two RPC services (XML-RPC or JSON-RPC) service."

https://manual.limesurvey.org/Global_settings

Comment: Seem you answer to your question …

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and this was because I had chosen the XML API instead of the JSON API in the general settings.